# Probability of biased dice

Tags: probability

A pair of dice are thrown, if each die is biased so that the probability of an even number appearing is twice the probability of odd number appearing, find the probability that the sum is 6.

I know the probability of even number appearing is 2/9 and probability of odd number appearing is 1/9, but can't find the combined probability that the sum is 6.

Any help? Please.

Comment: Hint: write down all the ways the sum could be $6$. Find the probability of each of those ways occurring.

Comment: You may have made a mistake in the probabilities you say you know - odd and even are the only possibilities but the probabilities you have don't sum to 1.

Comment: @ConMan He means the probability of any specific even number is $2/9$.

Comment: $P(2)=P(4)=P(6)=\tfrac 29$

Comment: Actually, I've assumed that we don't specifically know that P(1) = P(3) = P(5), but I'm not sure that you can solve the problem without that assumption ...

Comment: To obtain a value, you do need to assume the die are unbiased except as stated; and read "the probability of an even number appearing is twice the probability of odd number" as "the probability for *any* particular even number is twice that for *any* particular odd number".

Comment: @ConMan You're right it's not so clear from the problem, but like you said, without that assumption there's not enough information.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that after getting an expression for the probability of rolling a total of 6 and realising that it can probably take almost any value.

Answer (score 1):

The sum will be six if the first die is in 1 to 5 and the second die is its six-complement.   There are five such outcomes: three with double-odd die, und two with double-even die.

$$\{(1,5),(2,4),(3,3),(4,2),(5,1)\}$$

What are the probabilities for these outcomes?